# Declaring global variable not working (returning undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this basic set up and the problem I have is the variable `locations_map` in my function `load_heat2`. I indicated below where I'm getting the undefined:

```
//declare global variables

var full_map;
var locations_map;

function callIndex() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
 //call some functions
        load_map();
        load_test_map2();
        super_test_map();
        load_heat2(); 
    });

  $.ajax({
      url: 'php/get_map_tables.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'JSON',
       data: {
          client_id: client_id, //defined elsewhere
      },
        success: function(data) { //this gives me the correct data in the right variables
            var locations_map = data[0].locations_map;
            var full_map = data[0].full_map;
        }
});
function load_heat2(){
       console.log(locations_map); //this yields undefined
}

} //end of callIndex function
```

I'm trying to avoid wrapping everything in my AJAX/success function, so I need the global variable to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Ajax is async....this: `success: function(data) { //this gives me the correct data in the right variables
            var locations_map = data[0].locations_map;
            var full_map = data[0].full_map;
        }`...should be `success: function(data) { //this gives me the correct data in the right variables
            locations_map = data[0].locations_map;
            full_map = data[0].full_map; load_heat2(); //defined
        }`

Comment: This, along with removing the `var` when I declare the variables in my AJAX, was the trick I needed.

Comment: You should not rely on `success` handler of your `ajax` call to be executed before `$(document).ready`.

Comment: @Igor How would you structure this alternatively?

Comment: @jonmrich - I don't know if "I'm trying to avoid wrapping everything in my AJAX/success function" is your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring a local variable called locations_map in your success statement

```
 $.ajax({
  url: 'php/get_map_tables.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'JSON',
   data: {
      client_id: client_id, //defined elsewhere
  },
    success: function(data) { //this gives me the correct data in the right variables
        **var** locations_map = data[0].locations_map;
        var full_map = data[0].full_map;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks...this was part of the solution. The other thing I needed to do was load the `load_heat2` function as part of my success call (as pointed out by @robert-rozas)

Answer (score 2):

You are re-declaring the two variables in the ajax function.

```
var full_map;
var locations_map;
```

This is declaring them as global but when you set them here

```
success: function(data) { //this gives me the correct data in the right variables
      var locations_map = data[0].locations_map;
      var full_map = data[0].full_map;
}
```

It becomes local. In order for them to remain global you need to remove the

```
var
```

so it would look like

```
success: function(data) { //this gives me the correct data in the right variables
    locations_map = data[0].locations_map;
    full_map = data[0].full_map;
}
```

Comment: Thanks...this was part of the solution. The other thing I needed to do was load the `load_heat2` function as part of my success call (as pointed out by @robert-rozas)

Comment: The only reason you would need to call the load_heat2() function in the success function is because the ajax call is asynchronous and the load_heat2() method is getting called before the ajax call and because the variables don't have anything in them they return undefined which is still correct. loading the load_heat2() in the success function doesn't help make the two variables remain global. If you want to see whats in the data variable, a cleaner way would be to set a break point in the function in the dev-tools under source then set a watch on the data variable this is my favorite way.

Answer (score 2):

Call the load_heat2() function **after** you have the response of the ajax request. Also, remove the  "var" of both variables like the other answers are pointing.

```
  //declare global variables

var full_map;
var locations_map;

function load_heat2(){
       console.log(locations_map); //this yields undefined
}
function callIndex() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
 //call some functions
        load_map();
        load_test_map2();
        super_test_map();
    });

  $.ajax({
      url: 'php/get_map_tables.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'JSON',
       data: {
          client_id: client_id, //defined elsewhere
      },
        success: function(data) { //this gives me the correct data in the right variables
            locations_map = data[0].locations_map;
            full_map = data[0].full_map;
            load_heat2();
        }
});


} //end of callIndex function
```